# No route matches error: Difference between @model.association vs querying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Technically, I could get this working, but why my current code doesn't work confuses me.  I have a many-to-many relationship in my Events <> Users. This is where my view farts out, saying *No route matches: missing required key [:id]* ...

```
<% @event_users.each do |event_user| %>
 <%= link_to event_user.user.try(:full_name), user_path(event_user.user) %>
<% end %>
```

This is my code in my controller. One way that works, one way that doesn't work.

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
@event_users = @event.event_users    # This does NOT work
# @event_users = EventUser.where(event_id: 14)     # This does work
```

This is my controller relationships

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :event_users
end

class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :event, presence: true
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :users, through: :event_users
end
```

What exactly is going on here that I have to query and can't use the association to create a link? When I print out the text, I get the relevant data (the ID), so it should work. I've also tried this below and it still doesn't work.

```
<%= link_to event_user.user.try(:full_name), user_path(event_user.user_id) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to query `@event.event_users`, thats what the `has_many :through` association is for, you can simply use the `@event` object to get its users:

```
<% @event.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.full_name, user_path(user) %>
<% end %>
```

Note, you can also just pass an object to link_to that rails will automatically use a helper to create a route to `users#show`, like this:

```
<%= link_to user.full_name, user %>
```